# database connection

Tags: database

I want to create an wordpress website (Question paper genrator) in which there will be a button called *genrate paper* after clicking it a question paper should be genrated and question should be taken from database. In database i would create a table for questions and sr no. and whenever from website i click GENRATE PAPER then random question from database must be shown in a definite form. If anyone can help me it would help me alot, Thankyou in advance:)

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! We provide help with much more specific code questions, not general "how do I create a site that does X" questions. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help